# android app not working when screen goes off

Tags: java, android

I am new to android,
I am trying to run my application in the background but it does not.

Everything works fine but when the phone screen goes off, mHandlerTask stops working. When I turn the screen on the application continues working.

Here is the code:

```
package com.ekaspace.security.ekaspace;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class SecuritySystem extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_security_system);

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("URL"));
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
        mediaPlayer.start();

        mHandlerTask.run();

    }

    public void stopApp(View v) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 30;
    Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                String reqURL = "URL";

                URLConnection connection = (new URL(reqURL)).openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
                connection.connect();

                InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    html.append(line);
                }
                in.close();

                String response = html.toString();

                mTextView.setText(response);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                mTextView.setText(e.toString());
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Handler won't work as background service.

You need to use JobScheduler for API > 21, GcmNetworkManager or AlarmManager for lower versions, i suggest you to use this library : https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Answer (score 0):

You can not achieve this with handler. If you use handler.postDelayed(), the handler will stop when cpu sleeps (screen goes off). To achieve this you need to setup background services. Check [this](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) tutorial. You have everything explain there

Answer (score 0):

Handler part of Activity works when app is in forground so use Service for any background approach . Activity is not a medium to communicate in background

A service can run in the background indefinitely, even if the component that started it is destroyed.

here is the official link of service
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html